# Coffeescript global object not attached to window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, marionette

Im following a tutorial on writing a marionette app in coffeescript with rails. Namely Brian Mann's Backbonerails tutorials if you are familiar with these. My global app object is not available on the window when I inspect with firebug.

My **app.js.coffee**

```
console.log @

@App = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

App = new Marionette.Application

App.addRegions
    headerRegion: "#header-region"
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
    footerRegion: "footer-region"

App.on "initialize:after", ->
    if Backbone.history
        Backbone.history.start()

App
```

my **index.html.erb**

```
<div id="header-region"></div>
<div id="main-region"></div>
<div id="footer-region"></div>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
$(function() {
    App.start();
});
<% end %>
```

For the life of me I dont understand why I can console.log @ and receive a reference to the window object, but my App object is not attached to the window. Also receive reference error in console for App reference in index.html.erb

my **application.js** manifest file

```
//= require jquery
//= require lib/underscore
//= require lib/backbone
//= require lib/marionette
**//= require backbone/app**
//= require_tree ./backbone/apps
```

Comment: I would suggest trying `window.App = new Marionette.Application`. If that helps, I'll post an explanation. If not, could you show how you load `app.js.coffee`, and where you inserted the `console.log @` line?

Comment: thanks @Caffeinated.tech but that did not see not work. I have added my application.js manifest where I lead backbone/app using the rails asset pipeline. i console.log @ at the top of app.js.coffee.